# How to create a shopping cart in android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

i am trying to add shopping cart feature in my android app.I have a listview which is populated by json data using volley.On clicking listview item you view the item in Details.java,on clicking a button you save the said item in cart.I would like to know how to handle this cart feature.In [this](http://www.androiddom.com/2011/02/android-shopping-cart-tutorial.html) tutorial,they advised to create static variables for the items in a global class.Or should i use SQlite to save the data in cart?Any help will be appreciated.Please let me know if you need any code.Also you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163380/how-to-create-static-static-variables-from-a-json-downloaded-using-volley) for more details.

Answer (score -3):

This tutorial explains very well how you can secure your data in a webserver and even pay with paypal:

[**Android Integrating PayPal using PHP, MySQL – Part 1**](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-integrating-paypal-using-php-mysql-part-1/)